# How do we define the pdf in the multi-variate case and compute expectations?

Tags: expected-value, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function, measure-theory

Apologies if this is a very simple question but trying to work through a result in a paper made me realize I missed something a bit fundamental in my undergrad probability and analysis courses. Lets suppose we have $A\in \mathbb{R}^n$ which is a random variable with CDF $F_{A}(\cdot)$ and pdf $f_A(\cdot)$. For $h(\cdot):\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ I would write $$\mathbb{E}_{A}[h(a)]=\int_ah(a)dF_{A}(a)=\int_{a}h(a)f_{A}(a)da$$, but this doesn't make a ton of sense to me rigorously because our expectation and first integral evaluate to scalars whereas $da$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or at least I believe it is). What is the step I am missing in the evaluation of $dF_{A}(a)$? Are there resources people recommend to build this foundation more rigorously?

Comment: [Related?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/494238/expected-value-of-a-bivariate-distribution-as-an-integral)

Comment: I don't understand your confusion; "$da$" is literally just the dummy variable of integration in a standard Riemann integral, which is your right-most integral. The integral in the middle, on the other hand is a Riemann-Stieljes or Lebesgue-Stieljes integral. You can't read the notation in the two types of integrals in the same way!

Comment: The best resource would be any familiar Calculus or analysis textbook covering multiple integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: there is no inconsistency.  I want to make the following two remarks:

1. Merely from the differentiation perspective, your confusion is understandable.  For example, consider a bivariate function $F(x_1, x_2) = x_1x_2, (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, in differential form, the [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_differential_form) of $F$ is
   \begin{align}
   dF(x_1, x_2) = x_2dx_1 + x_1dx_2, 
   \end{align}
   which in appearance is completely different from $f(x_1, x_2)dx_1dx_2 = dx_1dx_2$.  Such difference may cause your confusion.
2. However, the above perspective is not the right way to understand the expectation formula, which essentially concerns **integration** instead of **differentiation**. It is a common misconception that "$dF_A(a)$" standalone is "evaluable", and it equals to "$f_A(a)da$" when the density exists (when $f_A$ exists, the Radon-Nikodym notation $f_A = \frac{d\mu}{da}$ is standard, but its correct interpretation is $(6)$ below, which has nothing to do with differentiation in calculus). Every piece in the notation "$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} h(a)dF_A(a)$" and "$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} h(a)f_A(a)da$" should be interpreted jointly rather than separately -- in particular, the integration operator "$\int$" should not be dropped.

---

**Longer answer**:  Below I will replace your r.v. $A$ with $X$ (because by convention, $A$ is more used to stand for events/sets instead of random variables), which is naturally defined on a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$.

By definition, the expectation of a r.v. $Y$ is the integral of $Y$ with respect to the probability measure $P$:
\begin{align}
E[Y] = \int_\Omega Y(\omega)P(d\omega). \tag{1}
\end{align}
When $Y$ is non-negative, the precise meaning (which is still a definition) of the right-hand side of $(1)$ is
\begin{align}
\sup\sum_i \inf_{\omega \in A_i}Y(\omega)P(A_i), \tag{$*$}
\end{align}
where $\{A_i\}$ is a finite decomposition of $\Omega$ into $\mathscr{F}$-sets, and the supremum extends over all finite decomposition of $\Omega$ into $\mathscr{F}$-sets.  As you can see, although the notation "$d\omega$" appeared in this measure-theoretic  definition, it has nothing to do with the elementary "differentiation" concept seen in calculus.  It merely is a notation.

If $X = (X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ is a random vector, and $h$ is a function from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, then $h(X)$ is still a r.v. from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$.  Therefore applying $(1)$ to $h(X)$ yields
\begin{align}
E[h(X)] = \int_\Omega h(X(\omega))P(d\omega). \tag{2}
\end{align}
(Side comment on the $"E_A"$ notation in your post:  Although it is seen in some literature, I always found that using the "$E_X[h(X)]$" to denote the right-hand side of $(2)$ redundant and misleading -- given the integrand is a function of $X$, the subscript "$X$" doesn't provide any new information hence should be dropped.)

As you may know, based on the probability measure $P$, $X$ induces a new probability measure $\mu$, on the Borel sets over $\mathbb{R}^n$, called the *distribution of $X$*, which is
\begin{align}
\mu(A) = P[X \in A] = P(X^{-1}(A)).  
\end{align}
The *Change of Variable Theorem* in probability theory connects $P$ and $\mu$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\int_\Omega h(X(\omega))P(d\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}h(x)\mu(dx). 
\tag{3}
\end{align}
Note that the precise meaning of the right-hand side of $(3)$ is exactly the same the measure-theoretic interpretation of $(1)$, just with a different measure $\mu$.

When $A = (-\infty, x_1] \times \cdots \times (-\infty, x_n]$, the set function $\mu(\cdot)$ can be converted to a point function $F(x_1, \ldots, x_n)$, which is called the *distribution function* of $X$.  Because of the defining relation $F(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = \mu((-\infty, x_1] \times \cdots \times (-\infty, x_n])$, the "$\mu(dx)$" in the right-hand of $(3)$ is often replaced by "$dF(x)$", whence $(2)$ and $(3)$ together can be written as
\begin{align}
E[h(X)] = \int_\Omega h(X(\omega))P(d\omega) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}h(x)\mu(dx) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} h(x)dF(x). 
\tag{4}
\end{align}
Although the right-hand side of $(4)$ also admits the "Riemann-sum" interpretation as for the one-dimensional Riemann integral (under which it is usually referred as *Riemann-Stieltjes integral*), it is recommended to interpret it just as a notational variant for $\int h(x)\mu(dx)$, as Billinglsley noted in Section 17 of *Probability and Measure*:

> *...Since these distinctions are unimportant under the context of general measure theory $\int f(x)dF(x)$ and $\int fdF$ are best regarded as merely the notational variants for $\int f(x)\mu(dx)$ and $\int fd\mu$.*

The point is: throughout the whole process $(2)$--$(4)$, there is really no place to "*evaluate $dF(x)$*" -- "$dF(x)$" is a notational variant for $\mu(dx)$, which in turn has to be interpreted as a part of measure-theoretic integral definition (i.e., there is no rigorous mathematical meaning for the standalone notation "$\mu(dx)$").

Finally, let's talk about density $f$ of $X$.  While $(4)$ holds for any random vector $X$, the relation
\begin{align}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}h(x)\mu(dx) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}h(x)f(x)dx \tag{5}
\end{align}
only holds when $\mu$ further admits the representation (a sufficient condition for $(6)$ to hold is that $\mu$ is dominated by $\lambda$, for which case $f$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative)
\begin{align}
\mu(A) = \int_A f dx, \tag{6}
\end{align}
where "$dx$" is essentially "$\lambda(dx)$", which means the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^n$. As before, both $(5)$ and $(6)$ are measure-theoretic integrals (with respect to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$) and shared the same interpretation as $(1)$. In particular, "$dx$" is not *a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$* (if you really want to make some geometric sense of it,  in view of the "$P(A_i)$" in $(*)$, it is slightly better to call it *a small rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^n$*, although I still discourage such isolated interpretation as stressed throughout this answer).